# Unit test always returns scala match error null or null pointer exception

Tags: scala, unit-testing

Currently trying to test authentication controller using specs2 and scalatest, my application runs fine, but the test always return NullPointerException or Scala Match error null

```
  val userRepository: UserRepository = mock[UserRepository]
  val userService: UserService = mock[UserService]
  val authenticator: Authenticator = mock[Authenticator]
  val authenticationService: AuthenticationService = mock[AuthenticationService]
  implicit val ec = mock[ExecutionContext]
  implicit val materializer = mock[Materializer]
  val authenticationController = new AuthenticationController(Helpers.stubControllerComponents(
    playBodyParsers = Helpers.stubPlayBodyParsers(materializer)
  ), authenticationService, authenticator, userService)

    "User" should "login successfully" in {
      val request = FakeRequest(POST, "/api/login").withHeaders(CONTENT_TYPE -> "application/json")
        .withBody[JsValue](Json.parse("""{"email": "nghia_hd@flinters.vn", "password": "a12306789H@"}"""))
      val result: Future[Result] = authenticationController.login().apply(request)
      result.map {data => data.header.status shouldBe OK}
    }
}
```

When using Intellij debugger, the exception seems to be here, but I dont really understand how to fix it

```
  def login: Action[JsValue] = Action(parse.json) {
    implicit request =>
      UserLoginForm.form.bindFromRequest.fold(
        formWithErrors => badRequestWarning(formWithErrors.errors),
        user => {
-->       authenticationService.verify(user) match {
            case Success(result) => success(UserPayload.encode(result))
            case Failure(exception) => exception match {
              case _: PasswordNotMatch => error(Unauthorized, 401, "Password not match")
              case _: EntityNotFoundException =>  error(Unauthorized, 400, "Email not found")
              case _ => error(InternalServerError, 500, "An error occurred")
            }
          }
        }
      )
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not used specs2/scalatest specifically, but usually you need to specify the response of the mocked method. You need to add this to the test:

```
when(authenticationService.verify(any())).thenReturn(someMockUser)
```

Otherwise (depending on your test settings) it will return null. There's also testing frameworks where you can instead throw an exception if methods that aren't mocked are called on mock objects.

Comment: It worked, thanks so much. Been struggling for days, thanks again for great help!!